# How to search display_name column when using WP_User_Query

Tags: php, query, wp-user-query

I'm using WP_User_Query to bring back a list of users. According to [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Search_Parameters), I can focus the query on particular columns (I'm assuming in the wp_users table) using the search_columns param.

My query:

```
$args = array(
    'search' => 'Rami',
    'search_columns' => array( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'display_name' ),
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

My aim is to have my query look in the display_name column but that doesn't seem to be working. Interestingly, display_name isn't a mentioned column in the [article example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Search_Parameters) but it is [definitely](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users) a column in the wp_users table.

How can I search the display_name column when using WP_User_Query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/**
 * Add support for the "display_name" search column in WP_User_Query
 * 
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166369/26350
 */
add_filter( 'user_search_columns', function( $search_columns ) {
    $search_columns[] = 'display_name';
    return $search_columns;
} );
```

where we use the [`user_search_columns`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/user.php#L652) filter to modify the available search columns.

So what fields can we use with this filter? Here's the list of all the fields in the `wp_users` table:

```
x ID
x user_login
  user_pass
x user_nicename
x user_email
x user_url
  user_registered
  user_activation_key
  user_status
  display_name
```

where I've marked the default search columns with an `x`.

Comment: Much better solution.

Comment: I updated the Codex page.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Search_Parameters), display_name isn't supported.

You could use the pre_user_query filter.

```
function henry_display_name_find( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    /* you don't say where the name comes from - this assumes a $_POST field */
    $display_name = $_POST['display_name'];

    $use_like_syntax = false;

    if ( $use_like_syntax = true ) {
        $query->query_where .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->users.display_name LIKE %s", '%' . like_escape( $display_name ) . '%' );
    } else {
        $query->query_where .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->users.display_name = %s", $display_name );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'henry_display_name_find' );
```

You'll probably want to add and remove the filter in a function.