# How to get user by display_name with WP_User_Query

Tags: php, query, wp-user-query

I'm using `WP_User_Query` to get user by `display_name` and other columns such as: `user_login`, `user_nicename`. Here is the code:

```
$my_users = new WP_User_Query(
            array( 
                'role' => 'technician',
                'search' => '*' . $search . '*',
                'search_columns' => array(
                    'user_login',
                    'user_nicename',
                    'user_email',
                    'user_url',
                    'display_name'
                )
            )
        );
```

It works if I search a user which display_name is `John Doe`, but if I search `Doe John` it obviously doesn't work. How can solve this problem? 
Thanks.

P.S. : I have enabled the `display_name` search in `functions.php` file using this code:

```
/**
 * Add support for the "display_name" search column in WP_User_Query
 * 
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/166369/26350
 */
add_filter( 'user_search_columns', function( $search_columns ) {
    $search_columns[] = 'display_name';
    return $search_columns;
} );
```

Comment: How would you handle the "John Smith Doe" search? Would you try all the 3! = 6 possibilities? What about 5 names?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a [fulltext search feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) on some of the `wp_users` table fields. That should be possible on the `VARCHAR` fields, but it would need some adjustments to the database and modification how the `WP_User_Query` search works. You could also just split the search string and do a query for each name.

Comment: @birgire it works if the name searched is written as it is written in `display_name` column

Comment: yes because the `"*John Doe*"` translates into a `LIKE '%John Doe%'` kind of search on the varchar fields. PS: I just changed this into a code block to fix the comment formatting problem when using a star in the text ;-)